# Stackoverflow Statistics

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users, statistics

Is there anyone out there regularly mining stackoverflow data and providing the stats online?

I know of [John's site](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/12/civic-duty-on-stackoverflow/) where he periodically posts some very interesting stuff.  But I've only been able to find data from earlier this year.  It would be interesting to see how this data changes as time goes on.

Answer (score 2):

The [graphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) tag provides a number of statistics resources.