# Any good use of creative commons license?

Tags: discussion

Has anyone seen any good uses of the stackoverflows creative commons license. I mean something like a blog listing the best recent questions or a wiki synthesising various answers into a unified view of a topic?

So far I've only seen this used for statistics:

- [Stackoverflow Statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32462/stackoverflow-statistics)
- [Stack Overflow stats graphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/stack-overflow-stats-graphs)
- [Sizes and overlaps of communities on the sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/sizes-and-overlaps-of-communities-on-the-sites)

Comment: Have you done any kind of a search first? Say, in the [statistics] or [data-dump] tags?

Comment: huh?  how does this question get closed as a duplicate of questions providing statistics about SO?  those "duplicate" links sound like *one good answer to the question*.  they do not seem to encompass the entire scope of this question.  (not to say this isn't a duplicate of *something*, but those are ridiculous.)

Comment: Can you vote to reopen then?

Comment: @Ether: Statistics are only one possible use for the creative commons license material. All user content is under cc too!

Comment: Has anyone ever copied answers or other information between Stack Overflow and a wiki with a CC license, such as Wikipedia? I could imagine that some of the better answers for some general questions might make good starts as articles or sections on Wikipedia.

Comment: I would think that a better way to ask the question is to ask for any good uses of the data, not just links to already implemented uses.  You might get more play that way.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as there doesn't seem to be anything out there, I have decided to start my own project to experiment with remixing content from http://casebash-experiments.wikidot.com/stack-overflow-remix.